# First Time If checking the parent node neither parent node getting checked nor child node getting checked

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-ui-window

I use Telerik kendo-tree-view to show popup  inside which all parent node is there
as checkbox.So when I should check parent node it should expand and check all child node automatically.But Not happening so and the issue is only for first time from second time working fine.

For first time when i check parent node it gets expand and have all child node but not checked.
Refer  the code below
Html part:

```
<div class="col-md-10  col-sm-10 remove-padding" id="parent">
                    <div style="height: 300px;overflow-y: auto;border:1px solid black" id="adminTreeView" kendo-tree-view="tree"
                         k-data-source="rc.adminTreeData"
                         k-options="rc.adminTreeOptions" tabindex="3">
                    </div>

            </div>
```

Angular part:

```
rc.adminTreeOptions = {
            dataTextField: 'DisplayName',
            checkboxes: {
                checkParent:true,
                checkChildren: true
            },
            check: onCheck,
        };

    rc.GetResourcePermission = function (roleId) {
                rc.adminTreeData = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: function (e) {
                            var id = e.data.Id || 0;
                            roleService.getHierarchyResourceByParentId(id, roleId, (rc.SelectedClient == '' ? null : rc.SelectedClient), CurrentAppId).then(function (response) {
                                e.success(response);
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "Id",
                            hasChildren: "HasChild"
                        },
                        parse: function (response) {
                            return $.map(response, function (x) {
                                x.checked = x.Checked;
                                return x;
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    requestEnd: function () {
                        if (roleId != 0) {
                        if (angular.element("#adminTreeView").data("kendoTreeView") && angular.element("#adminTreeView").data("kendoTreeView").expand) {
                                angular.element("#adminTreeView").data("kendoTreeView").expand(".k-item");
                            }
                        }
                    },
                });
            }
```